# Remotely unlocking LUKS encrypted Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I encrypted Raspbian using `aes-cbc-essiv:sha256` algorithm with 256-bit key using LUKS and configured it to remotely unlocking.

I followed these tutorials:

- https://learn.adafruit.com/resizing-raspberry-pi-boot-partition/edit-partitions (for know how to extend boot partition),
- https://robpol86.com/raspberry_pi_luks.html (for know how to prepare LUKS encrypted Raspbian),
- http://paxswill.com/blog/2013/11/04/encrypted-raspberry-pi/ (for know how to prepare Dropbear and its keys),
- https://sowhatisthesolution.wordpress.com/2016/03/20/unlock-luks-via-ssh-in-debian/ (for know how to establish internet connection during initramfs boot),
- https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/ (for copy and paste `crypt_unlock.sh` script).

When I'm trying establish ssh connection with encrypted device, I'm dropped into BusyBox shell and everything work:

```
hubot@debian:~$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rpi_dropbear root@192.168.1.3
To unlock root-partition run unlock


BusyBox v1.22.1 (Raspbian 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

~ # unlock
Please unlock disk /dev/mmcblk0p2 (sdcard): 
cryptsetup: sdcard set up successfully
Connection to 192.168.1.3 closed.
```

However, if I'm trying ssh connect with unlocked device, I'm getting following error on my client PC:

```
hubot@debian:~$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 22: Connection refused
```

When Raspberry Pi boots, I can see following error:

```
Error: unexpectedly disconnected from boot status daemon
```

On https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/ author wrote:

> This error doesn’t seem to happen if LUKS passphrase is directly
>   entered at the server console.

but I want to be able remotely log in ssh into unlocked encrypted device. Can anyone help me?

Comment: After you boot into device with remote password. Can you attempt to manually restart ssh daemon `service ssh restart` or print the daemon status `service ssh status`, there is a chance that the socket is still bound when the service starts.

Comment: @crasic the output from `service ssh status`: http://paste.asie.pl/pUci, after restarting ssh service I can log in into ssh.

Comment: Aha, well there is your problem, unfortunately the status, as always, is rather uninformative. We do know that the service fails to start. The most likely root cause is that dropbear has the port still bound when it starts `systemd` and proceeds to boot. See if there are any messages in kernel log `dmesg | grep ssh`

Comment: @crasic The output from dmesg: http://paste.asie.pl/jefg